# ngrx effects property payload does not exist on type never

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Upgrading ngrx I keep getting this message in my Effects files

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I keep forgetting this because it's so obscure.

## Gotcha 1

You have to scroll down in your code of your effects file and change the input of your constructor from using:

```
private actions$: Actions
```

to

```
private actions$: Actions <auth.AuthActionsUnion>
```

## Gotcha 2

From within your action file, scroll to the bottom and make sure you are adding all your types to the union.

ex:
[image]

Comment: please explain what is the 'union' for variable all?